# Web.xml invalid element name

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

[jndi-name invalid element error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKWJQ.jpg)

Invalid element jndi-name is the error I receive, I am using WildFly.

This is a project we have been doing as a group but when trying to run it on my personal computer or the university Virtual Machine this is an error I receive. I'm not sure if I'm missing anything that is required.

I am running this on Eclipse 2019-12

Comment: Try not to provide text information via screenshot links. Please, instead, add the formatted text to your question. Also, please provide background info. For example, what web container are you using (e.g Tomcat, etc.)?

Comment: Also, for more context: How are you using the `jdbc/CustomerDS` reference name in your code? Typically, something like `(DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/CustomerDS")`.

Comment: I am using WildFly, I'm not sure about the 'jdbc/CustomerDS' I believe it has been copied from my lecturers example code.

Comment: Understood - you should edit your question. And add `wildfly` as a tag, also.

Comment: Open this with the XML Editor and flip over to the design tab. Does resource-ref require children in a certain order? Are you sure jndi-name is really valid there?